# Which formula should I use in order to get total number and minutes of malfunction?

Tags: excel-formula

Using only "vlookup" does not work because there are a bunch of malfunctioning minutes & total numbers of it. So as I know I should combine "vlookup" with "sum" or I am wrong? please support me on this query.

[image: taskscreen]

Comment: SUMIF, SUMIFS or SUMPRODUCT would be functions to explore

Answer (score 0):

You can use Countif() to count with conditions and Sumif() to sum up numbers that fulfill a condition.

In cell K10 (count System No malfunctions)

```
=Countif(A:A,K9)
```

... in words: count the rows in column A whose text is equal to that in cell K9.

In K11 you can conditionally sum with this formula:

```
=Sumif(A:A,K9,C:C)
```

... in words: for all the rows in column A whose text is equal to that in cell K9, sum the values in column C.

Copy the two formulas from K10 and K11, paste them into K15 and K16 and change the reference from `A:A` to `D:D` to look at the code column instead of the system number.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.